# If $m=\omega(N log N)$, then what is the order of $N$ in terms of $m$?

Tags: limits, algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics, order-theory

> Assume $m=\omega(N \log N)$. What is the order of $N$ in terms of $m$?

My answer: I found that if $N=m^{1-a}$ where $0<a<1$, then $m=\omega(N \log N)$ holds. But, I think this is not a good representation.

Then I thought of Lambert $W$ function. I think we can say $\log{N}=o(W(m))$ thus $N=o(e^{W(m)})$. But, I need more simplification.  I should know the asymptotic behavior of $W(m)$ as $m \to \infty$. Any idea?

Comment: The answer is in pages 27-38 of  NG de Bruijn Asymptotic Methods in Analysis NorthHolland

Comment: Please let me know if you understand my answer; feel free to ask if you need clarification on the method.

Answer (score 0):

$N$ is of order
$\dfrac{m}{\log m}$.

To see this,

$\begin{array}\\
N \log N
&=\dfrac{m}{\log m} \log(\dfrac{m}{\log m})\\
&=\dfrac{m}{\log m} (\log(m)-\log \log m))\\
&=m-\dfrac{m\log \log m}{\log m}\\
&=m(1-\dfrac{\log \log m}{\log m})\\
&=m(1-o(1))\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean $N=o(m/log(m))$ is exactly equivalent to $m=\omega(N \log N)$? Is that little o?

Comment: The result holds whether you use $o$ or $\Theta$ or just about anything.

Comment: Thanks. But you have shown that $N=o(m/\log {m} )$ results $N log{ N} = o(m)$. This is just one side. It is not proved that $N log{ N} = o(m)$ yields $N=o(m/\log {m} )$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any variables $m,N \ge 0$ such that $m \in ω(N \log(N))$ as $N \to \infty$.
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

Given any constant $c > 0$:

As $m \to \infty$:

If $N > c \cdot \lfrac{m}{\log(m)}$:

$N \to \infty$.

$m \ge \lfrac2c \cdot N \log(N) > 2 \lfrac{m}{\log(m)} ( \log(m) - \log\log(m) + \log(c)) > m$.

[since $2 \log(m) > \log\log(m)$ as $m \to \infty$]

Contradiction.

Therefore $N \le c \cdot \lfrac{m}{\log(m)}$.

Therefore $N \in o(\lfrac{m}{\log(m)})$ as $m \to \infty$.

---

If it is not clear why the above proof is valid, you can translate it as follows. If there is a sequence of points for which $m \to \infty$ but $N > c \cdot \lfrac{m}{\log(m)}$, then $N \to \infty$ for that sequence, and we will get a contradiction in exactly the same way. Therefore given any sequence of points for which $m \to \infty$, eventually $N \le c \cdot \lfrac{m}{\log(m)}$.