How to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+y+4}{x-y-6}$?
I have started learning ODE and I couldn't solve this exercise:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+y+4}{x-y-6}$$
I am a beginner and only learned separation of variables and how to solve homogeneous equations by using $y=ux$ but I don't think this problem can be solved by any of these.
I tried to use sub $x-y=u$ but I didn't get anything useful from this,

Try to make the ODE homogeneous by substituting $X=x-h$, $Y=y-k$.

This question is similar to: A specific homogeneous polar differential equation. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search. Although the other question uses $-3$ instead of $+4$ in the denominator, and $-1$ instead of ...

(cont.) $-6$ in the denominator, the procedure to follow is basically the same. Note there are also quite a few other very similar questions, such as Solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x-y+2}{2x-y+3}$, that's listed in the RHS "Related" section.

Substitute $x=X+h$ and $y=Y+k$ where $h, k$ are constants$\big{(}$, i.e., $\mathrm dx=\mathrm dX$ and $\mathrm dy=\mathrm dY\implies\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm dY}{\mathrm dX}\big{)}$ such that the ODE becomes homogeneous:
$$\frac{\mathrm dY}{\mathrm dX}=\frac{X+Y+(h+k+4)}{X-Y+(h-k-6)}$$
For the ODE to be homogeneous, we get the system of equations:
$$h+k=-4$$
$$h-k=6$$
Hence, $h=1, k=-5$.
Now, the ODE becomes:
$$\frac{\mathrm dY}{\mathrm dX}=\frac{X+Y}{X-Y}=\frac{1+\frac{Y}{X}}{1-\frac{Y}{X}}$$
Where $X=x-1, Y=y+5$. This can be easily solved by the substitution $Y=tX$.

If $x=X+h, y=Y+k$ how  to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $\frac{dY}{dX}$?

More importantly: If $x= f(X,Y), y=g(X,Y)$ What is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $\frac{dY}{dX}$?

@One In general you need a Jacobian determinant, but in this case $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}Y}{\mathrm{d}X}$.

@J.G. I comepletly forgot about this, I need to revise this any recommendation on what book to use? It would be better that it has a lot of exercises

@One $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm dY}{\mathrm dX}$ since $h$ and $k$ are constants, see my edited answer.

@MathGuy I don't understand what is $dY$ and $dy$ without a fraction (what did you differentiate both of them ?), it is seem like cheating.

@One these are differentials and such notation is absolutely valid. Think of $\mathrm dx$ as an infinitesimal change in $x$. You must've encountered these in chain rule and separation of variables too(while cross-multiplying $\mathrm dx$).

I know what they are but I on't understand how does that works, Is  there a rigorous way to prove this?

@One well this is indeed rigorous. $Y$ can be considered as a function of $y$: $Y(y)=y+5\implies \mathrm dY=1\cdot\mathrm dy$ by the definition of differentials. Similarly, it can be shown that $\mathrm dX=\mathrm dx$.

@MathGuy hmmm I think I need to revise, but I don't recall learn about this or using this in real analysis/ calculus

@One also, the concept of differentials is applied to solve exact DEs where exact differentials such as $d(xy)=ydx+xdy$ are widely used.

I don't like this since it appear to be an abuse of notation

@One you may like to see this.

According to me, there is no harm in writing and doing stuff like this unless we try to delve into its philosophical aspects.

I agree that it appears to be an abuse of notation. I've always thought of differentials intuitively as denoting very small changes in variables. I'm in high school, and till now such an understanding seems plausible to me, although I've seen on other threads here on MSE that this is not strictly correct, but for now, even my teacher has said to go by this intuitive definition only. TBH, I'm kinda confused about dx
too, but when I go by its intuitive definition, all seems well.

@One you may want to go through these threads: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142783/separable-differential-equations-detaching-dy-dx/2142793#2142793, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27425/what-am-i-doing-when-i-separate-the-variables-of-a-differential-equation

@One Did you finally understand how $\mathrm dY=\mathrm dy$ and $\mathrm dX=\mathrm dx$? If that’s still not clear, let me remind you that you would’ve used differentials a lot in $u$-substitutions in integration, eg: $u=\sin x\implies\mathrm du=\cos x\mathrm dx$.
